# MySQL: Find birthdays between a date range, but ignoring the year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to query for users with birthdays falling between a given date range.

The `users` table stores birthdays in a pair of `int` columns: `dob_month` (1 to 12) and `dob_day` (1 to 31). The date range I'm querying with is a pair of date-time strings, including the year.

Here's what I've got so far:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', 2023, dob_month, dob_day)) BETWEEN '2023-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-03-31 23:59:59'
```

However, this doesn't work when the date range spans multiple years.

For example, `2023-12-15 00:00:00` and `2024-01-10 23:59:59`.

How can I work around this? Thanks!

Comment: Surely in this case a simpe `WHERE dob_month = '03'` would be simpler

Comment: You don't need to create a date using DATE() function. You can compare dob_month and dob_day directly if you want to ignore year part.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that was just a simplified example. The date range is driven by a web app, and could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by joining to a set of rows with individual dates.

Suppose you had another table called `dates` which had one row per day, spanning the whole range you need.

```
mysql> create table dates (date date primary key);

mysql> insert into dates(date) 
 with recursive cte as (
  select '2023-01-01' as date 
  union 
  select cte.date + interval 1 day from cte where cte.date < '2025-01-01'
) 
select * from cte;
Query OK, 732 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now it's easy to query a subset of dates:

```
mysql> SELECT date
FROM dates
WHERE dates.date BETWEEN '2023-12-15 00:00:00' AND '2024-01-10 23:59:59';

...
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We create a sample user with a dob of January 3.

```
mysql> create table users ( id serial primary key, dob_month tinyint, dob_day tinyint);

mysql> insert into users set dob_month = 1, dob_day = 3;
```

You can join your users table to that subset of dates where the month and day match.

```
mysql> SELECT date FROM users JOIN dates 
  ON dob_month = MONTH(date) AND dob_day = DAY(date) 
WHERE dates.date BETWEEN '2023-12-15 00:00:00' AND '2024-01-10 23:59:59';

+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2024-01-03 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Great answer! Upvoted... But any way to solve this without a separate table? I don't have `CREATE TABLE` permissions (at least not without jumping through a ton of hoops, anyway...!)

Comment: Yes, use a common table expression. There are examples of generating a series of date values on the manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, the logic is to convert dob_month and dob_day into a date and then do the comparison using `BETWEEN` operator.

Now the year value used for date conversion is based on the below logic :

*Use the year value the same as that of "from date". If the date is less than the "from date", then push it to the next year. Use `BETWEEN` operator to check if the date is within the given date range. This logic is applied because to use BETWEEN operator the date has to be greater than or equal to the "from date" keeping month and day values intact.*

Note `Date_add(Date_add(Makedate(some_year_value, 1), INTERVAL (dob_month)-1 month), INTERVAL (dob_day)-1 day)` is repeated 3 times. It is for creating a date out of the year, month, and day values.

```
SET @fromdate = date('2023-09-01 00:00:00');

SET @fromyear = year(@fromdate);

SET @todate = date('2024-02-28 23:59:59');

CREATE TABLE users
  (
     id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     dob_month TINYINT,
     dob_day   TINYINT
  );

INSERT INTO users
SET dob_month = 2,
    dob_day = 1;

SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN Date_add(Date_add(Makedate(@fromyear, 1),
                           INTERVAL (dob_month)-1 month),
                      INTERVAL (dob_day)-1 day) < @fromdate THEN
         Date_add(Date_add(Makedate(@fromyear + 1, 1),
                  INTERVAL (dob_month)-1 month),
         INTERVAL (dob_day)-1 day) BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
         ELSE Date_add(Date_add(Makedate(@fromyear, 1),
                       INTERVAL (dob_month)-1 month),
                     INTERVAL (dob_day)-1 day) BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
       end;
```

Psuedo code for understanding the crux:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN Date(from_date_year,dob_month,dob_day) < @fromdate THEN
         Date(from_date_year,dob_month,dob_day) BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
         ELSE Date(from_date_year + 1,dob_month,dob_day) BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
       end;
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the date range is, for example, between `2023-12-15 00:00:00` and `2024-01-07 23:59:59`.

Comment: Updated the answer as per your inputs @Jack